# Wrap button around icon?

Tags: android, xml, android-button, material-components-android

how can i remove that gap after the icon? how can i Wrap button around icon normally?

[image]

```
    <Button
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"

        
        app:icon="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18"
        app:iconTint="@null"/>
```

Comment: You are using `Button`. That is designed for a text caption with an optional drawable. If you want just the icon, use `ImageButton`.

Comment: @CommonsWare if i replace with imagebutton, the button collapses to a miniscule rectangle. look here: https://i.imgur.com/qe4Egl9.png

Comment: this is why i didn't use imagebutton

Comment: Instead of `app:icon`, you would use `android:src`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton).

Comment: @CommonsWare ok now the  size is good but my custom icon is showing up without colors. why?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any direct way of doit it but did some tweak to help you out

Create Button without wrap content give some width as per your design look and feel.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_google_hangouts"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />
```

In code do the following changes and play with adjusting padding per your requirement.

```
 val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    button.setPadding(24,0,0,0)
```

the image dimension which I used for testing is 24dpX24dp

my final result:

[image: final image]

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a **`ImageButton`** as suggested in the comments
- You can use the **`MaterialButton`** with this style:

  ```
  <style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.IconOnly">
    <item name="iconPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
    <item name="iconGravity">textStart</item>
  </style>
  ```

Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.IconOnly"
            app:icon="@drawable/...."
            app:iconTint="@null"/>
```

[image]